# Configuring an IP address in Spring Boot admin client

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am using Spring Boot admin version 2.6.9 and using

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.prefer-ip=true
```

to register to admin server via an IP address. Now since I am running my apps inside [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) containers, the admin server receives Docker IP addresses and not the public IP addresses
of the applications.

I have tried changing *management.address*, but that does not work.
I can not use the Docker network to connect to these machines and I can not change the *server.address* property. I have tried the below properties as well, but they don’t show anything on the admin server apart from online status.

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url=http://11.0.134.202:9999
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.management-url=http://11.212.134.202:9999
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.prefer-ip=true
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-url=http://127.0.0.1:9999
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.management-url=http://127.0.0.1:9999/actuator
```

Comment: prefer-ip has been deprecated, I can't find the substitution...